# Excel - Dynamically currency exchange rate in SUMPRODUCT

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have transactional table looks like

| NO | TRANS DATE | HOST FROM | HOST TO | CCY | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 09 Oct | A | D | USD | 10 |
| 2 | 10 Oct | A | E | USD | 5 |
| 3 | 10 Oct | C | D | GBP | 3 |
| 4 | 10 Oct | B | F | EUR | 2 |

From the transactions above, I need to consolidate to movement table by DATE, by HOST NAME and by its HOST CCY

| DATE | HOST NAME | HOST CCY | AMT MOVE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 Oct | A | USD | -5 |
| 10 Oct | B | EUR | -2 |
| 10 Oct | C | GBP | -3 |
| 10 Oct | D | USD | -3*0.81 |
| 10 Oct | E | USD | +5 |
| 10 Oct | F | EUR | +2 |

Expectation of consolidation table is as AMT MOVE column as above, which means that it will deduct HOST FROM, and add to HOST TO with CCY converter:

- If HOST TO and HOST FROM are the same CCY, it will be original CCY (e.g. transaction NO. 2 and NO. 4).
- If HOST(s) are in different CCY, HOST FROM will be deducted by original CCY and HOST TO will be added by converted to its CCY (e.g. transaction NO. 3)

Exchange rates table based on local USD:

| CCY | FX RATE |
| --- | --- |
| USD | 1 |
| EUR | 0.94 |
| GBP | 0.81 |

I have tried `SUMPRODUCT(*SUMIFS(exchange rate table))`, but it can only convert whole to 1 CCY while consolidation table is much more dynamic converting among HOSTs' CCY.

Please help, super thanks.

Comment: You might think about creating a "helper" column that holds each AMT in a common currency (USD, GBP, or EUR?). With that column, you're dealing with a single currency to populate the resulting table, and THEN convert from the common currency to the "original" currency in the result table. That might simplify things.

Comment: Just drafting something out, but I'm getting a bit confused - wouldn't D be increased by 3/.81 dollars resulting in $3.7  rather than reduced by 3*.81 in transaction 3 because three pounds is worth more than three dollars and it is receiving the amount?

Comment: Thank @PeterT, but tables are not editable, only AMT MOVE in resulting table is able to play around.

Comment: Thank you, @TomSharpe, you are right, I took FX table by mistake. It should be in inverse way, but just keep multiply to make it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible answer, though not sure of the exact meaning of 'original' currency. The basic idea is to work out the transactions in dollars, then convert to 'original' currency at the end.

To get dates:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LET(unique_dates,UNIQUE(Table1[TRANS DATE]),DROP(REDUCE("",unique_dates,LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(UNIQUE(VSTACK(FILTER(Table1[HOST FROM],Table1[TRANS DATE]=c),FILTER(Table1[HOST TO],Table1[TRANS DATE]=c))))),c)))),1)),ROW()-ROW(Table3[#Headers])),"")
```

To get unique host names per date:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(LET(unique_dates,UNIQUE(Table1[TRANS DATE]),DROP(REDUCE("",unique_dates,LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(a,UNIQUE(VSTACK(FILTER(Table1[HOST FROM],Table1[TRANS DATE]=c),FILTER(Table1[HOST TO],Table1[TRANS DATE]=c)))))),1)),ROW()-ROW(Table3[#Headers])),"")
```

To get host currency:

```
=IF(@[HOST NAME]="","",XLOOKUP("*"&@[HOST NAME]&"*",Table1[HOST FROM]&Table1[HOST TO],Table1[CCY],,2))
```

To get amt move

```
=IF(@[DATE]="","",(SUMPRODUCT(Table1[AMT]/XLOOKUP(Table1[CCY],Table2[CCY],Table2[FX RATE])*(Table1[HOST TO]=@[HOST NAME])*(Table1[TRANS DATE]=@[DATE]))-SUMPRODUCT(Table1[AMT]/XLOOKUP(Table1[CCY],Table2[CCY],Table2[FX RATE])*(Table1[HOST FROM]=@[HOST NAME])*(Table1[TRANS DATE]=@[DATE])))*XLOOKUP(@[HOST CCY],Table2[CCY],Table2[FX RATE]))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you my hero, you saved my life with your logical ideal ```work out the transactions in dollars, then convert to 'original' currency at the end.```

Comment: And sure, your formular works great. To be more clarify, the resulting table are provided with HOST NAME and HOST CCY, and they are repeated through the days, just small edit to your formula in AMT MOVE to add backward converter to SUMPRODUCT of HOST TO side: ```*XLOOKUP(@[HOST CCY],Table2[CCY],Table2[FX RATE])```